# Show that $a = 1$ if $(x - 3)$ is a factor of $x^3 - 8x^2 + ax + 42$ and $a$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$(x - 3)$ is a factor of $x^3 - 8x^2 + ax  + 42$ where $a$ is an integer

Show that $a = 1$

I don't know where to start with this... Any insight?

Comment: Have you tried synthetic division?

Comment: Have you heard of the Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Have you learned polynomial long division?  (equivalent to synthetic division) I.e. start doing long division of $(x^3-8x^2+ax+42)/(x-3)$ and show what $a$ must be to give remainder 0.

Comment: No, we've never gone through it. GCSE Further Maths is rock hard...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As $x - 3$ is a factor of the given equation, and since $x - 3 = 0$ when $x = 3$, put $x = 3$ in the equation:

$(3)^3 - 8(3)^2 + a(3) + 42 = 0$

$27 - 72 + 3a + 42 = 0$

$3a - 3 = 0$

$3a = 3$

$a = 1$

Comment: Cheers man, I had no idea that was possible.

Comment: As stated, this is backwards and misleading. $x-3$ being a factor does not make $x - 3 = 0$. Instead, since $x-3$ is a factor, setting $x = 3$ makes $x - 3 = 0$, and the since the original polynomial is something multiplied by $x-3$, when you set $x = 3$ in it, the value of the polynomial is therefore a multiple of $0$ and so equals $0$ itself. From there the rest is correctly stated.

Comment: I think the potentially "misleading" part is just that a couple of steps are not explained. We _want_ to work "backwards" in the sense that the more typical process derives a factor from a root. The missing bits are, since $x-3$ is a factor **we know the polynomial is zero if** $x-3=0,$ **which is true if** $x=3,$ **and therefore if we** put $x=3$ in the equation, (continue as shown in the answer).

Comment: Agree with @PaulSinclair -- edited to correct the wording.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $x-3$ is a factor of $x^3-8x^2+ax+42$, then $x^3-8x^2+ax+42$ can be written as $(x-3)$ times something. Importantly, this means that when $x=3$, $x^3-8x^2+ax+42=0$. Use this to find $a$.

Comment: Does this mean I should use factorisation?

Comment: @Charlie You do not need to do that explicitly. Plugging $x=3$ back to the polynomial is enough for finding the value of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The property ‘$x-3$’ is a factor of the polynomial $p(x)$ simply means $p(3)=0$, since the remainder of the division of $p(x)$ by $x-\alpha\;$ is equal to $p(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

You may recall in the past that you would find roots of a polynomial to help factor it; e.g. $3$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x)$ if and only if $(x-3)$ is one of the factors of $f(x)$.

What you are overlooking is that you can use this *same fact* in other ways. Rather than using roots to find a factor, use the factor to find a root.

If $(x-3)$ is a factor of $x^3 - 8x^2 + ax  + 42$, then $3$ is a root of $x^3 - 8x^2 + ax  + 42$.

If $3$ is a root of $x^3 - 8x^2 + ax  + 42$, then $3^3 - 8 \cdot 3^2 + a \cdot 3  + 42 = 0$.

This is an equation you can solve for $a$.